# What does the new keyword mean in a interface

Tags: typescript

If I have the following interfaces:

```
interface CustomElementConstructor {
    new (...params: any[]): HTMLElement;
}

interface CustomElementRegistry {
    define(name: string, constructor: CustomElementConstructor): void;
}

interface Window {
    customElements: CustomElementRegistry
}
```

What types is the `constructor` parameter constrained to? See from the interface definition I would expected it to be a object which has a constructor which returns a type of `HTMLElement`. But for the following, TypeScript throws a error (and the source is indeed invalid):

```
class X {
  constructor(): HTMLElement {
    return document.createElement("div") as HTMLElement;
  }
}

customElements.define("hi", X);
```

Is this because TypeScript does not declaring a different return type other than itself for a constructor? Or is there something more complex around the `new` value in a interface...?

Comment: No time to write a full answer, but I think your confusion lies here: "I would expected it to be a object which **has** a constructor". It should be an object which **IS** a constructor which returns a type of `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error you get is `TS 1093: Type annotation cannot appear on a constructor declaration.`. This is because in a `class` definition, the constructor always returns an instance of a class, in this case, an instance of `X`.

And that also explains the next error, which is `TS 2345: Argument of type 'typeof X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'.`. The constructor returns an instance of `X`, and an instance of `X` (A.K.A. an object of type `X`) has no properties from `HTMLElement`.

I think you want to define the class `X` as a subclass of `HTMLDivElement`, so each instance of `X` is also a valid instance of `HTMLElement`, like this:

```
class X extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

customElements.define("hi", X);
```